# wordpress custom post type remove duplicate menu item

Tags: custom-post-types, php, menus

I've registered a new content type with following -

```
register_post_type('news', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'News'),
        'singular_name' => __( 'News'),     
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New News', 'News'),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New News'),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit News'),
        'new_item' => __( 'New News'),
        'view_item' => __( 'View News Details'),
        'search_items' => __('Search News')         
      ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_position' => 6,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'news'),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor' ),
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'menu_icon' => plugins_url('icons/news.png', __FILE__),
    )
);
```

This does generate admin menu item as follows --

[image]

or

[image]

Is it possbile to remove repeated link for menu item **News** that comes on `hover` of main menu item. Because, the main menu item **News** ( in bold letter ) takes admin to same page as sub-menu item news does. In short- i want to have only two options as sub menus .. those are *Add New News* and *Categories*. Is this possbile ??

I tried using following--

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_news_subitem');
function remove_news_subitem() {
    global $submenu;
    unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=news']);
}
```

But this removes all submenus.

I believe no such *hook* is present to do this. And only option I could imagine is to edit core files. But that I **strongly** don't want to do.

Possible way to do this using jQuery when menu items render on domReady. But this is ugly. Can it be done from php itself??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added `'all_items' => __( '' ),` in labels array.

Replace your code with below code

```
register_post_type('news', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'News'),
        'singular_name' => __( 'News'),     
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New News', 'News'),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New News'),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit News'),
        'new_item' => __( 'New News'),
        'view_item' => __( 'View News Details'),
        'all_items'          => __( '' ),
        'search_items' => __('Search News')         
      ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_position' => 6,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'news'),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor' ),
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'menu_icon' => plugins_url('icons/news.png', __FILE__),
    )
);
```

Comment: I found `remove_submenu_page()` does same thing. But your approach is what I'm going to adapt. I'm having number of such post types and calling `remove_submenu_page()` for each is not good. This solution clean and simple avoiding multiple func calls.